# Find and Replacing values in a jobject

Tags: c#, json.net

I've got a json object that looks like this:

```
{
  "name" : "http://request.to.website1",
  "name2" : "value2",
  {
    "type: : "http://request.to.website1"
  }

},
  "name" : "http://request.to.website2"
  "name2" : "value2",
  {
    "type: : "http://request.to.website1"
  }
{
```

I'm writing a tool that reads in the json above, resolves what is at that URL, then replaces the url in the json with the result from that request.

I'd like to query the jObject for values that start with a url then replace that value with what I want.

Psuedocode for something I'd like to do:

```
JObject modelJson = (JObject)JToken.FromObject(model);
modelJson.Values.Where(m => m.startsWith("http://").foreach(m => m.replace(makewebrequest(m))
```

Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: You could change the serialized json in a string directly by using RegEx.

Comment: Your json is incorrect, how does your model looks like, please share it

Comment: your json is invalid and also your pseudocode contains compile time error.

Comment: What are you expecting to get back from the web request, a plain string, or more JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic example of how you can parse some json, iterate through the JObject content, find out if a key/value is what you need, set the new value and return the value for the specific json key.

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    var json = @"
    { items: [
    {
      ""name"": ""http://request.to.website1"", 
      ""name2"": ""value2"", 
      ""type"":  ""http://request.to.website1""
    },
    {
      ""name"": ""http://request.to.website2"",
      ""name2"": ""value2"",
      ""type"": ""http://request.to.website1""
    }
    ] }";

    var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

    using(var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        foreach (JObject o in jObject["items"].AsEnumerable())
        {
            foreach (var token in o)
            {
                var url = token.Value.Value<string>();

                if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute))
                {
                    o[token.Key] =  "new content"; // await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var modifiedJson = jObject.ToString();
}
```

[image]